# Is it ok to split a web site in two portion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am developing a social network. This network requires its content easily readable by google. At the same time, i want to give perfect user experience with fully ajax support. As you know ajax and google not good friends(as far as i know). I tought a solution that split web site in to 2 pieces of views on a same URL(for all sites URLs):

1. Authenticated users.
2. UnAuthenticated users.

As you expect Authenticated users will get fully ajax support and excellent user experience. And when google's bots come to me social network as a UnAuthenticated user it easily can read all the content(of course no ajax any more).

On the other hand, I know that there is a technic called Hijaxing. But it seems hard to implement for all site.

I am gonna use
1. Asp.net mvc 3,
2. jQuery

What you think, what should i do? Thank you :)

Comment: Also generally, I would not recommend showing search engines (such as Google) one thing and users another as you could run the risk of search engines thinking your 'cloaking'. A quote from Google: "Make pages primarily for users, not for search engines. Don't deceive your users or present different content to search engines than you display to users, which is commonly referred to as "cloaking." Reference: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769

Comment: Please not another social network.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make AJAX content crawlable by Google. See [here](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to create a Google friendly home page (non authenticated users) and once a user is loged in, you can use all ajax-javascript you want.

Don't worry about the private sections (google bots can not enter there), but for public sections you'll need to take care of writing unobtrusive JavaScript (jQuery helps a lot on this). Try to open the page with JavaScript disabled in your browser, if you can read the important keywords, google will do as well.

Also, Google bots can point to #hashed urls. [Google Ajax Crawling](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) gives you more information on this.

Good luck, your "social network" will be a very very complex project. Much more than you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a guide that you can use to expose your AJAX content to its crawlers. You can find it here : http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Ideally, you'd be making a fully functional site that doesn't require AJAX to work. But this may not always be possible or desired with modern web applications.

Also, I'd assume that Authenticated and Unauthenticated users would have a different experience in any case? If yours is a social network, most of your content would be behind a privacy wall (unless it's mostly open). If it's all open, I'd suggest that you use those guidelines to expose the content rather than building two sites.

Comment: all social networks content open. and yes in 2 cases users will get different experiences.